# MSAL with MERN stack web app for authentication and authorization

Tags: node.js, reactjs, authentication, oauth, azure-ad-msal

I have got a scenario where I need to implement the authentication and authorization using Azure AD b2c through MSAL, where I'm confused should I use MSAL for nodejs or the react js one. I have gone through official msal-nodejs documentation however its kind of unclear. It would be great if any one can help me on how to achieve this or if you have any example of msal with MERN stack app that would be great!

Comment: Don't forget to upvote useful answers and accept answers that resolve your question. It costs you nothing and rewards the effort that others have put in to help you.

Answer (score 2):

Check the below MERN example:
https://github.com/Azure-Samples/ms-identity-javascript-react-tutorial/tree/main/3-Authorization-II/2-call-api-b2c

Essentially:

- MSAL-React is used to handle the authentication of the React frontend.
- From your React frontend, you call your Node.js API passing the accessToken acquired with the help of MSAL.
- Passport.js is used on the Node.js API to validate the accessToken